# How can I make a folder automatically recursively give certain permissions in MacOS?

Tags: macos, permissions

I know how to share a folder, and I know how to recursively give permissions to everything in a folder.

What I would like is to do this automatically.  I want to have a folder that is never owned by any user, it is always shared, anything put into there has "everyone" permissions, etc.

It's a public folder for all users, everything that gets put into is is also public.

How do I do this in MacOS?

Comment: See [this similar question on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/permissions-for-new-files-in-shared-directory/7255).

Comment: Ah.  It seems the best way is a cron job with the answer `sudo chmod -R +a "staff allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /Users/Shared/reallyshared`